# Why does MATLAB report an invalid argument at 'position 1' in this example?

Tags: matlab

Take a look at this [script](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html)

```
function [m,s] = stat3(x)
    arguments % valid for MATLAB® R2019b and later.
        x (1,:) {mustBeNumeric, mustBeFinite} 
    end
    n = length(x);
    m = avg(x,n);
    s = sqrt(sum((x-m).^2/n));
end
```

Running this line

```
values = [12.7, 45.4, 98.9, NaN, 53.1];
[ave,stdev] = stat3(values)
```

yields this error

`Invalid input argument at position 1. Value must be finite.`

Obviously, `NaN` is not at position 1. Any clarification regarding the meaning of `position` in the error's message?

Comment: I suspect because there is only 1 position, which contains  the vector `[12.7, 45.4, 98.9, NaN, 53.1];`.

Comment: @AnderBiguri , are you saying it points to the row's number?

Comment: Yes, I assume that is what it does. Try changing the check to `x (2,:)` and inputting a 2x5 matrix that contains NaN in the second row

Comment: In this cases `values` is a row vector not a column vector, so `x(1,:)` load everythings that is in the first row, since `values` has only one row, `x(1,:)` is the whole vector. You have two options: `1)` `values` should be a column vector: `values = [12.7, 45.4, 98.9, NaN, 53.1].';` `2)` in your function check for the column `x(:,1) {must...` or even simpler, `x(1) {must...`.

Comment: Ooh, I like that new syntax! Are you sure it's not `position 1` meaning `x` is the first argument of the function? What happens if you define `function [m, s] = stat3(y, x)` and call it with `stat3(0, values)` for example?

Comment: I think [this page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-argument-validation-1.html) supports my interpretation (see the end of the section titled **Avoiding Class and Size Conversions**), but I can't test this as I don't have R2019b yet. I think `position 1` refers to the position of the validation statement in the `arguments` block. MATLAB refers to the location of an element in a vector as its 'index', not its 'position'.